# How to auto-increment non primary key

Tags: sql, django, django-models

I have the following django model:

```
class Message(models.Model):
    thread_id = models.IntegerField(max_length=8, blank=False)
    subject = models.CharField(max_length=256, blank=False)
    content = models.CharField(max_length=5000, blank=False)
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, blank=False)
```

I want to auto-increment the `thread_id` when adding a Message model object (from a specific view) even though it isn't the `pk` for the model. Is there a way to do this without querying the db to find the large thead_id and adding one?

Comment: This is probably easiest (and most efficiently) handled in your database rather than in django.  But you don't mention which DB you're using, so I can't be 100% sure.

Answer (score -8, accepted):

Use [AutoField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.AutoField) instead of IntegerField

Comment: You cannot use AutoField as a non-primary key field.

Answer (score 3):

Shouldn't Thread be a separate model, with its own autoincrementing PK, and Message just keeps a ForeignKey to Thread?

Comment: Thanks for the response, it prompted me to ask a follow-up question related to db design for this feature -- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7926388/comparing-two-db-designs-for-internal-messaging.

Comment: Daniel - ideally yes, but sometimes when the related object has no additional info, it's easier to maintain a flat structure, e.g. in this case `thread_id` is just an integer with no additional info

Answer (score 0):

In my project I'm using count. Here is some code.

```
def ids():
no = Employee.objects.count()
if no == None:
    return 1
else:
    return no + 1

emp_id = models.IntegerField(('Code'), default=ids, unique=True, editable=False)
```